# Problem With 3 Screens

Tags: nvidia

As the image shows, every time I turn on my computer the screen (number 1) configuration of my notebook get lost, and it shows half of my 2 other screens.

If I drag the screen 1 to the right side of the screen 2 in the display settings the problem got fixed and I can drag back to the original position without any problem and use it normally.

I have a RTX2060 with 1 HDMI and a display port; and I'm using the driver X.OrgXserver--Nouveau display driver (open source).

Anyone know how I can fix this problem?

[image: 3 screen problem photo]

Answer (score 0):

Your screens appear to be overlapped in your configuration.

In the display settings, you should drag display #2 farther to the right so that it does not overlap display #3

Comment: They aren't. If u look this picture, all 3 screen are ok. But if a turn off my computer, next time i turn on. They'll be bugged. Picture -> https://ibb.co/n8MxWBf

Comment: File a bug report.  In the meantime, you're going to have to manually adjust them.  Another option is to use a different layout

Comment: I gonna do this!! Ty!! :)